# Roi (Região de interesse) customizado com Opencv e python

Tags: python, opencv

Eu faço a detecção de pessoas usando Opencv e python, mas preciso personalizar a minha ROI. Só consigo desenhá-la retangular, gostaria de uma forma customizada como na figura.
[image: foto da roi personalizada que preciso]

Comment: É possível criar uma ROI não retangular usando uma máscara do tamanho da imagem (imagem totalmente zerada) e desenhando o polígono que você deseja (pontos pintados de branco).

Comment: Como poderia fazer isso? Tem algum exemplo que possa seguir?

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo em https://gist.github.com/begnini/0194ba7f26e23a8c18d37f6188062922

Comment: Olhei lá, rodei o código mas fica tudo preto. Carreguei a minha imagem em "image = cv2.imread ( ' minhaImagem.jpg ' )" e dei um cv2.imshow("roi", masked) e ficou tudo preto.

Comment: O meu codigo gera a seguinte imagem https://i.imgur.com/kojGSku.jpg

Comment: Vc tá exibindo a imagem com cv2.imshow('roi',masked)? Aqui tá dando erro justamente no imshow pra exibir a masked. Dá erro de acessibilidade "Error retrieving accessibility bus address", mas só quando mando exibir com imshow, se comento o imshow, roda sem erro, mas não vejo nada. rsrsrs

Comment: Eu criei uma polilinha (cv.polylines) para servir de base e consigo ver o desenho da área para ter uma referência. Mas não estou conseguindo fazer a detecção, com retângulo consigo. Uso o código da seguinte forma: gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame[:,:], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    detect_area = gray[y_DetectAreaA:y_DetectAreaA+h_DetectAreaA, x_DetectAreaA:x_DetectAreaA+w_DetectAreaA]


people = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        detect_area,
        scaleFactor=1.4,
        minNeighbors=45,
        minSize=(35, 35),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )